# How to specify plot lines/bands with data?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I know it's possible to add plot lines and bands when initializing chart from axis properties. Also it's possible to do it using `addPlotBand()` API function. But I would like to specify line/band points along with series data. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean by saying "along with series data". Could you provide some example?

Comment: inside `series` property, where you specify plot data. But already found an answer.